# Problem in RecyclerView Adapter AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-studio-3.6

i use Android Studio Version 3.6 with API 29 and i has problem in the recycler View Adapter  in this code

```
@NonNull
@Override
public MyView onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.exampel,parent,false);

    return new MyView(view);
}
```

why i cant use the getContext()??

Comment: could you let us know what is the problem you are talking about? you can add error log to your question. adding current and expected behavior helps understand the question better.

Comment: Please give us more context so that we can better help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `RecyclerView.Adapter` doesn't have a `getContext()` method. 
You can use `parent.getContext()` instead

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView.Adapter does not have a getContext() you need to use the parent context.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public MyView onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

View view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.exampel,parent,false);
 return new MyView(view);
}
```